# Unable to display FragmentActivity in Scrollable Tab Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a TabsPagerAdapter class that I use for my scrollable tabs in my Android app. However, the problem is that in one of my tabs I have a FragmentActivity and I am unable to return the class in my scrollable tab.

I am not sure what to do. If I remove

`import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.InstalledAppActivity;`

I still receive an error.

[image]

Here is my InstalledAppActivity class :

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import com.javatechig.listapps.ApplicationAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class InstalledAppActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

    ListView InstalledAppList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.installed_apps);

        InstalledAppList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Installed_List);
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();

        InstalledAppList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(i);
                try {
                    Intent intent = packageManager
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

                    if (null != intent) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }





    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, container, false);


    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        boolean result = true;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.main_text: {
                displayAboutDialog();

                break;
            }
            default: {
                result = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void displayAboutDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.slogan));


        builder.setPositiveButton("Know More", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://javatechig.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No Thanks!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
    //first attempt
  /*  @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        InstalledAppList.setOnItemClickListener()
        //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }*/


     //2nd attempt
 /*   private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener OnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView InstalledAppList, View v, int position, long id) {
            ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
            try {
                Intent intent = packageManager
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

                if (null != intent) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    };*/

    //third attempt



    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(InstalledAppActivity.this,
                    R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            InstalledAppList.setAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(InstalledAppActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my TabsPagerAdapter class as well:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.CustomList_Activity;
import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.InstalledAppActivity;
import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.Pre_InstalledApp_Activity;



public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new InstalledAppActivity();
            case 1:
                return new Pre_InstalledApp_Activity();
            case 2:
                return new CustomList_Activity();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Moreover when I try to use the autocorrect it says that refactoring cannot be performed. And when I try to change it to `return new Fragment();` instead nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   the problem is that in one of my tabs I have a FragmentActivity and I am unable to return the class in my scrollable tab.
```

It expect to return a `Fragment` not a `Fragment Activity`. Also `FragmentPager` does not accept an `Activity`, that Activity cant be instantiated only Fragments are allowed.

**Documentation** for `FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment that is persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user can return to the page.
```

**solution:**

return a Class that extends `Fragment` not `Fragment Activity`

Comment: Unfortunately the last solution I had to creating the InstalledAppActivity was having a class that extends FragmentActivity so if in this case I would produce the same error I had last time.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment Activity is actualy  an Activity that has support for hosting fragments not a Fragment

Comment: How can I fix it in this case? because I need the FragmentActivity in my InstalledAppActivity

Comment: You need to create FragmentActivity that will manage your fragment and move your UI logic into new class that extends Fragment